# What is the database config for a codeigniter PHP56 running on linux 14 connecting to a remote mssql server

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, codeigniter, pdo

We recently migrated our PHP server from Microsoft to a Linux server. Before we were using the "pdo-sqlsrvr" configuration. But now we don't know what to follow. I've been doing some reading and found that we should use the "pdo-dblib" to connect to the remote MSSql server but our problem is that we don't know what configuration to use for the CodeIgniter. Since most of the examples go like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

And our updated CodeIgniter database config file is this:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'dblib:BIOSQL\SQL; dbname=mydb;',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'mydb',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

this returns an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
```

I really am blind here and I don't know what to do to configure this properly using the pdo-dblib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this connection string :

```
$db = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

for instance :

```
$db = new PDO ("dblib:host=BIOSSQL\SQL;dbname=mydb","username","password");
```

Also SELinux can be issue sometimes, run these once :

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```